# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to get a LocalDate

Tags: java, android, retrofit, localdate

I´m trying to get a LocalDate with Retrofit but it doesn´t works.

I get this error: E/Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 35 path $[0].fecha_alta
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4jaP.png)

Retrofit class:

```
public class Client {
public static Retrofit getClient(String url) {

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new JsonDeserializer<LocalDate>() {
        @Override
        public LocalDate deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
            return LocalDate.parse(json.getAsString(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
        }
    }).create();

    return new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build();
}
```

}
POJO:

```
    @Generated("com.robohorse.robopojogenerator")
public class Profesores implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("dni")
    private String dni;
    @SerializedName("fecha_alta")
    private LocalDate fecha_alta;
    @SerializedName("direccion")
    private String direccion;
    @SerializedName("fecha_nac")
    private LocalDate fecha_nac;
    @SerializedName("nombre_grupo")
    private String nombre_grupo;
    @SerializedName("usuario")
    private Usuarios usuario;
```

Code where it´s called:

```
 public void getListaProfesores() {
    //Se crea una instancia de llamada a la API
    apiService = Network.getInstance().create(ApiService.class);
    //Se llama al servicio que obtiene los profesores
    Call<List<Profesores>> call = apiService.getProfesores(grupo);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Profesores>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Profesores>> call, Response<List<Profesores>> response) {
            listaProfesores = response.body();
            profesorAdapter = new ProfesorAdapter(ListaProfesoresActivity.this, listaProfesores, ListaProfesoresActivity.this::onProfesorClick);
            recyclerViewProfesores.setAdapter(profesorAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Profesores>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Error", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```